# Prevent fixed element from overlapping

Tags: html, css

I have a footer div for a mobile site, which needed to be at the bottom of the screen.
This is the code:

```css
#footer {
position:fixed;
bottom:10px;
width: 95%;
right: 0;
left: 0;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
background:#fff;
min-width:240px;
border-radius:5px;
padding:3% 0;
}
```

It's working fine, however when the content reaches the div, its overlapping my footer. I'd like to position my footer in the normal content flow, coming right after other content when they reach it.

Comment: Is there a reason you make it fixed, if you want to have it in the normal content flow?

Comment: Flow and `position:fixed` do exclude each other. As you say `mobile`: https://www.google.de/search?q=ios+position+fixed&oq=ios&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j69i59j69i61j0l3.9275j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The z-index attribute accepts a number value.  Most people use the highest limit as 9999 and the lowest as -9999.

The elements with a higher value will appear above elements with a lower value.

However, you can't place a parent element above a child element with z-index.

```
#footer {
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

---

edit: since your saying you want it to behave like a normal div, try this

```
#footer {
    position: relative; 
    margin: 20px auto;
}
```

position:fixed sets an element to a fixed position based on the window (screen size). It always stays where you put it.

Comment: Thanks the answers, however z-index is not a solution for me. I'd want the footer behaving like a normal div. It's still wrong when it's overlapping other elements.

Answer (score 0):

Set the z-index of the footer to 100

```
#footer {
    z-index: 100;
}
```

and the one of the now overlapping div to 1

```
#mydiv {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Like i said: I'd like to position my footer in the normal content flow, coming right after other content when they reach it.